# How to duplicate only the first row of SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel-2010

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008, and I'm trying to write a query that returns Excel 2010 appointment data for a specific user, for importing/exporting reasons. However, the first result that gets returned is never properly imported into Excel. To solve this issue, I'm trying to duplicate the first row of the results just one time, so that I will be able to correctly import all of the appointments. I thought about nesting a query inside of another query to somehow duplicate just the first appointment that is returned, but my query needs to be generalized, as it will be run for thousands of different users. An example of what I'm looking for is as follows:

```
Title
-----
Meeting A
Meeting A
Meeting B
Meeting C
Meeting D
etc...
```

Comment: You could do a union with a copy of your query that returns just the top 1 result (assuming they are ordered). But I would look into why the import is incorrect rather than try to duplicate your data.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is because Excel is expecting the first column of import data to be the header of the column, such as Meeting Name, Organizer, Start Date, etc. I am just able to access the data, so I just want to prevent appointments from being missed. Unions are a good idea, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i do these type of queries to export and then import in excel, i Usually do:

```
SELECT 'COLUMN1NAME','COLUMN2NAME'
UNION
SELECT * FROM TableName;
```

This way, when you open it in excel, you already have your header.